# Компиляция нескольких Android приложений из одного исходного кода

Tags: директива, android, java, компиляция

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно скомпилировать два разных приложения из одного исходного кода. Эти приложения отличаются только package name и ресурсами.

Я хотел использовать аналоги `#ifdef   #define` , но оказалось, что их попросту нет...

Конкретнее - мне нужно что бы в одном и том же файле исходников в случае компиляции приложения использовался файл ресурсов(R) одного приложения, а для другого приложения - другой файл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все очень даже реально. Есть такой проект - antenna, он формально реализовывает препроцессор. Почитать как сделать и что скачать, можно на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107652/).

В нескольких проектах испытывал, достаточно нормально работает.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Создал два батника для препроцессинга кода для разных приложений. 
А вообще жаль, что в джаве все еще нету директив...

Comment: В джаве много чего ещё нет. И вряд ли будет. Но разве это проблема? можно всегда либо сваять костыль, либо написать по правильному.

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно добавить тег Java может кто и поможет более точно. Я сомневаюсь что это невыполнимая задача (уж если в плюсах такое есть...). Погуглите системы сборки для Java проектов (к сожалению не силен в Java технологиях).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй создать Android Library. Выносишь туда ресурсы и код, которые повторяются и используешь хоть в гуглеоне приложений.

Answer (score 2):

Известные грабли. Проблема решается в 2 этапа:

1. Вместо `#ifdef/#ifndef` надо использовать `public static final boolean flag=true/false;`. Это конечно же не совсем директивы препроцессора, но в плане удешевления кода лепту свою вносит, поскольку в финальном бинарнике компилятор все равно отбросит неработающие ветки.
2. Нужно иметь несколько манифестов, каждый из которых имеет собственный лончер активити.

Если хочется совсем уже красоты, то можно вокруг этого обернуть `ant` скрипт, чтобы автоматизировать переключение между ветками.

На стэке я уже [отвечал на аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507784/multiple-android-application-package-apk-files-from-single-source-code/7664530#7664530)

Comment: если бы все было так просто...
дело в том, что в "общих" для двух проектов файлах я использую ссылку на файл ресурсов(R), а он должен импортироваться из разных пакеджей для каждого приложения...

Comment: Ресурс генерируется один и тот же по контенту, но разных пакетах. Пакет назначается в манифесте. Тут есть небольшая хитрость: надо сгенерировать и скомпилировать ресурс для одного аппы (пакета) и затем его же использовать для другой аппы (пакета). Если не делать rebuild то все будет работать. У меня с одних исходников генерируется 3 аппы: demo, light и full - и все нормально. Я просто меняю манифесты не перестраивая ресурсы и все.

Answer (score -1):

Вряд ли так получится, создай 2 разных проекта с разными ресурсами.

Если очень хочется, скинь все ресурсы в одну папку и просто подставляй кодом нужные картинки в зависимости от параметра компиляции.